# Вывод данных из mysql для определённого пользователя

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

У меня есть 2 таблицы, с пользователями и заказами, нужно вывести данные на страницу, только для того пользователя, чей номер указан в таблице с заказами, он должен совпадать с номером в таблице с пользователями(нужно их сравнить), если в заказе указан другой номер, то у пользователя не должны выводиться данные по заказу.
Я написал небольшой запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN users
ON orders.phone=users.phone
WHERE orders.phone=users.phone;
```

Но он выводит данные из таблицы с заказами для всех пользователей, нужно исправить это недоразумение, буду благодарен за помощь :)

Answer (score 0):

Выводит для всех пользователей потому что вы указали всех, а нужно для одного. Вам не нужно трогать таблицу пользоваталей. Всё просто:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE phone='Телефон конкретного пользователя'
```

Answer (score 0):

В условиях WHERE не нужно связывать столбцы, вы это cделали в ON. Вот такой вариант:

```
SELECT * FROM orders LEFT JOIN users ON orders.phone=users.phone WHERE users.phone='Номер телефона'
```